# How to handle pymongo AutoReconnect exception with insert_many method

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert, replicaset

I have a MongoDB replica set with 3 members and a Python application which stores data in it.

I can handle pymongo's `AutoReconnect` exception when using single document inserts with a wrapper as follows:

```
def safe_mongo_call(method, num_retries, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        try:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        except (pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect,
                pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError) as e:
            if num_retries > 0:
                logger.debug('Retrying MongoDB operation: %s', str(e))
                num_retries -= 1
            else:
                raise
```

I'm not sure though how to handle these exceptions when using bulk writes, e.g. `insert_many` method. According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/), bulk writes are not atomic, so even if one of the exceptions occurs, there might be already some documents written to the database successfully. Thus, I can't simply reuse the wrapper method as above.

What's the best way how to handle these situations?

Comment: Relevant: https://gist.github.com/anthonywu/1696591

Comment: The code you provided does basically the same thing to what I posted in the question. My use case is different and involves bulk operations which can't simply be retried because part of the documents can already be written to the database.

Answer (score 3):

For this case there’s **BulkWriteError** that must provide details on what’s been done
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#ordered-bulk-write-operations

But in case of connection loss **AutoReconnect** is sent instead and the info on the operation progress appears to be lost (tested for pymongo==3.5.1)

In any case you'd need to reconstruct what's been written and what not and retry the operation for the remaining items.
In the latter case it'd be a bit harder as you don't have prior info on what's been actually written but still doable

As a sketch solution:
each document to be inserted is assigned an **ObjectId** unless **_id** is already present. You might handle this yourself - iterate over the documents, manually assign **_id** for those missing it and save the IDs in a temporary variable. Once you hit an exception find the last **_id** successfully inserted leveraging i.e a binary search-like approach to have at worst ~O(logN) queries, and maybe also use the fact bulk operations are split into smaller batches (https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#bulk-insert). But of course applicability of this approach is up to the load profile you have on your mongod instances and whether additional queries bursts are admittable. If **BulkWriteError** were thrown as expected, you could just grab documents that are not inserted and retry the operation for these docs only.

Back to the  **AutoReconnect** problem, I'd personally open a ticket in *mongo-python-driver* issues tracker,  chances are high its either a bug or being done like that on purpose

Comment: I checked all this but that's the problem, if `AutoReconnect` is thrown, it lacks information about what has been done so far. Can you elaborate on how to *reconstruct what's been written*? Because it's not that easy, taking into account there can be multiple places from where writes can come from and also items can have the same semantic keys (not being duplicates).

Comment: Augmented my answer

Comment: Opening a ticket might be a good direction, at least to find out if there are technical reasons why it's done this way.